# How to stop celery worker?

Tags: linux, python, redis, celery

I am running celery via redis. I start my worker like this:

```
celery multi start worker1 -A mypackage.tasks.tasks
celery multi v3.1.18 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
        > worker1@polyphemus.xxx.net: OK
```

And I kill it like this:

```
celery multi kill worker1
celery multi v3.1.18 (Cipater)
> worker1@polyphemus.xxx.net: DOWN
```

But the worker is actually still running. I can not start the worker again:

```
celery multi start worker1 -A mypackage.tasks.tasks
celery multi v3.1.18 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
ERROR: Pidfile (worker1.pid) already exists.
Seems we're already running? (pid: 29369)
        > worker1@polyphemus.xxx.net: OK
```

If I kill the process, everything is ok:

```
kill 29369
```

But that is too cumbersome: I need to know the PID. How to *really* kill the worker with the celery command line tool?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to stop the worker with `celery multi` command. You can get PID from pid file or from ps output, e.g.

```
ps auxww | grep '[c]elery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

or

```
kill $(cat /path/to/worker.pid)
```

Comment: What?! According to the `celery multi` help message, *there is* a `celery multi kill worker1` command. What is that supposed to do but to kill the worker?

Comment: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker - it's not documented. I've checked with the source code, it does exactly the same but in python.

Comment: That command actually does nothing. Try it and see. After `celery multi kill` you will still see the processes running...